# Неправильный путь к базе SQLIte при создании jar

Tags: java, sqlite

При создании jar на рабочем столе приложение не работает и пишет в блоке catch:

"path to 'sqlite\form4.db': 'C:\Users\Avandy\Desktop\sqlite' does not exist
"

однако при перемещении jar в рабочую папку программы где лежит база SQLite - подключение происходит, всё работает. Вот код подключения к базе:

```
static void connect() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sqlite\\form4.db");
        co.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Прошу подсказать как собрать проект так, чтобы jar был неважно где, а путь к базе был прописан конкретно. Может быть дело в переменной окружения, где я прописал в CLASSPATH ";."?

Answer (score 0):

Можете задавать путь на диске прямо в коннекшен-стринге. Например так:

```
jdbc:sqlite:C:/YOUR_PATH/form4.db
```

Comment: так а если у человека, который скачает jar, по этому пути не будет базы?

Comment: Вынесите путь в проперти или берите из переменных окружения.

Comment: А отправил я jar человеку, он откроет - ничего не сработает..

Comment: Вам надо упаковать базу в jar?

Comment: Да, но чтобы приложение искало базу в самом jar, а не на диске..Или код как создавать новую базу у коллеги на компьютере при запуске программы. Альтернативу консоли sqlite3 - ".open name.db"

Comment: Если Вы упакуете базу в jar, Вы не сможете производить запись в нее. Только читать. Насчет создания новой базы  - это происходит автоматически при вызове `DriverManager.getConnection` в случае если файла по указанному пути нет.

Comment: откуда sqlite базу данных jar взяли? дайте ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось, когда написал название BD без указания пути - "jdbc:sqlite:form4.db".
При запуске jar в этой же папке была создана база form4.db и form4.db-journal, который исчез после закрытия